# Copy And Replace System Files Which are in use

Tags: windows-7, filesystems

I have edited authui.dll (first I copied it form Sys32 folder on my desktop and then edited it) which is related to windows logon. Now After edition I need to copy and replace it back into sys32 folder, I have full permission but when I try to copy it, an error will appear and tells that it is in use...

How to copy and replace such system files?

Comment: do it offline, using a live CD of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't while the system in running. Windows does have a way to schedule file moves for the next boot. A command line utility to schedule such a move is available from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals) included with the [PendMoves](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897556) command line utility.

```
movefile c:\changedDLLs\authui.dll c:\windows\system32\authui.dll
```

Keep in mind Windows also has a way to check for modified system files and replace them so it might get reverted unless you take additional steps.

Comment: How did you stop windows from verifying systemfiles then?